# ASP.NET ~ remotely invoking an ASP.NET page

Tags: asp.net

I have two servers running IIS, say, Server-A and Server-B. Server-A is in the DMZ, visible to all users; Server-B is not in the DMZ. I need to provide a way for users to invoke a page on Server-A which will in turn remotely request a page on Server-B, transparently to the user. In other words, Server-A needs to do this on behalf of the user because the user does not have visibility to Server-B.

Is this possible and if so, what is the best method to do this?

Comment: It would be better to use ASMX or WCF for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, this is possible. You want the [WebRequest](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webrequest.aspx) class.

Answer (score 0):

As long as Sever-A can see Server-B you can use a WebClient, though I agree with the comment that WCF or ASMX would be better

```
System.Net.WebClient wc = new System.Net.WebClient();
var html = wc.DownloadString("WebPageAddress");
```

then you can do what you want with the returned string